AWS RDS Postgres as DMS Source Endpoint - Setting up user for replication
I’m trying to follow the instructions from this link and I realised I don’t have access to a superuser after seeing this step:
Log out of the OtherThanMaster account and log in with an account that has the rds_superuser role assigned to it.
How do I create a superuser or be able to do these next steps, am I missing something?
It turns out my postgres user is not the master user, even though it shows in the console that Master username: postgres and I cannot seem to find a way to get something like that, rdsadmin is owned by AWS, right? Running this query SELECT * FROM pg_roles WHERE rolname = 'postgres'; shows me:



rolname
rolsuper
rolinherit
rolcreaterole
rolcreatedb
rolcanlogin
rolreplication




postgres
false
true
true
true
true
false



Postgres version: 15
